# ImageMagick: resize a image and merge it with another

Tags: imagemagick

I try to merge 2 images (put the logo.png on top of pic.png) to a new file newpic.png.

```
convert pic.png logo_.png  -gravity southwest -compose over -composite newpic.png
```

But logo.png should be resized before the merge (not the file but the image that is used for the merge). 
I tried -resize and -size but both affected newpic.png.

Any idea how I can produce that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use parenthesised *"aside processing"* to ensure the resize operation only applies to the logo:

```
convert pic.png \( logo_.png -resize 80x40 \) -gravity southwest -compose over -composite newpic.png
```

Or, apply the resize while you only have one image loaded, then load the other image and swap the order ready for compositing:

```
convert logo.png -resize 80x40 pic.png +swap -gravity southwest -compose over -composite newpic.png
```